# Is there a way to read an external json file in jmeter and use it's values for another request?

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way by which we can have the JMeter read the contents a .json file and use its values in POST body of another request? What would be the necessary steps?

Answer (score 2):

There is [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) which reads the given file, you can use this function directly in the "Body Data" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler (or wherever you like)

[image]

More information: [How to Use JMeter Functions - Part III](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii)